# Why is there no package feed when using NuGet.Server

Tags: nuget-server

I followed the [Creating Remote Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) directions at nuget.org to create a server.  I created a .NET 4.0 project and imported the NuGet.Server package, put my own NuGet package file in /Packages and ran it as an ASP.Net 4.0 application under IIS 7.5.  Everything seems to work except that I get a 404 message if I try to view the package feed at ~/nuget.  It seems that the atom feed isn't getting started at all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ~/nuget/Packages? Can you verify the routes are added to your application on startup?

On a sidenote, it may be worth exploring [MyGet](http://www.myget.org) or [ProGet](http://www.inedo.com) as alternatives to your own feed as well.